# Is there an easy way to know what line of jQuery script called an event?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

I'm working on a drupal module (irrelevant) and I'd like to recreate a javascript/jQuery event. If I use chrome and go to event listeners I see the jQuery script is called on line 57, however this doesn't really help as:

- The script is minified and unreadable
- I'd like to know what line of
  the jQuery using scripts called the event (what selector and what
  body of it's function), not the jQuery script itself
- It's not easy to find the file by just
  searching for fit selectors as there are 100's of loaded javascripts
  files thanks to drupal and it's installed modules.

The reason is that I'd like to recreate this (ajax probably) call:
[image]

So does anyone know of a trick like a chrome plugin or something? It could shave a lot of time for me.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you are setting a correct breakpoint then you should be getting a `Call Stack` on the `Source` Tab, on the right hand side. There you should be able to track down the file which initiated the call.

And as they say, *a picture speaks a thousand words..*

[image: Jquery Trace the call to the file.]

And to further elaborate on your question,

It is always advisable to use an uncompressed jQuery.js (Or for that matter any .js) during the development, as you might have already figured out.

***Steps for someone new.***

1. Inside the compressed file just get the version no.
2. Download the respective uncompressed version of the jquery from the **[official website](https://code.jquery.com/jquery/)**.
3. If you don't want to change the code just rename the uncompressed file to `jQuery.min.js` or whatever is currently being loaded, so It will work as a drop in replacement.

Comment: I'd like to add that if you use Chrome you can skip downloading the uncompressed version and jut click on the brackets in the lower left corner of your code view (it's also visible in the screenshot next to the line and column numbers) and it will show an uncompressed version.

Answer (score 0):

Try chrome devtools, for example:

```
Sources -> Event Listener Breakpoints (to the right) -> Mouse -> click
```